# Laravel 4 Loading all songs from a playlist in database

Tags: php, laravel

Hey guys like explained in the heading I'm having a bit of trouble with Laravel,
I'm creating a system that a user can have various playlists (up to 5) and in each playlist is able to have a lot of songs (up to 50). I am trying to incorporate all this into this and trying to print it out as follows:

I have the following Class for Playlists:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

    <?php
    class Playlist extends Eloquent {
        /**
         * The database table used by the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = 'playlists';
        public $timestamps = false;
        /**
         * Whitelisted model properties for mass assignment.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $primaryKey='playlistid';

        protected $fillable = array('playlistname', 'userid');

        public function songs()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('Song', 'playlistid');
        }
    }




And the following class for a song:
```

```html
       <?php
        class Song extends Eloquent {
            /**
             * The database table used by the model.
             *
             * @var string
             */
            protected $primaryKey='songid';
            protected $foreignKey='playlistid';
            protected $table = 'songs';
            public $timestamps = false;
            protected $fillable = array('songname', 'songurl', 'playlistid', 'position');
    
            public function playlistid()
            {
    return $this->belongsTo('Playlist', 'playlistid');
            }
    public function fromList($id)
    {
    return $this->where('playlistid', $id);
            }
        }
```

And then I am trying to call it in my homepage like:

```html
        @foreach (Song::find(1)->fromList(1) as $song)
        echo $song->songname
        @endif
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, does anyone know a better way to do this or a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but here's how you print all the songs of one playlist:

```
@foreach(Playlist::find(1)->songs as $song)
    {{ $song->songname }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: You're welcome. Just wait 5 more minutes and then you can accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it.